# Passing the $_GET [id] to being refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, session

I have a developed a chat application. Once a user submits using keyup, it works well i.e inserted into database and also selected just fine and the message is even displayed. The page being refreshed by javascript is load.php which has php code doing the selection like this;

`SELECT * FROM chat WHERE sender_id=$_SESSION['id']`

This is working just fine. But when I change it to

`SELECT * FROM chat WHERE sender_id=$_SESSION['id'] AND receipent_id=$_GET['id']`

it is not working simply because the `$_GET['id']` of a selected member in the home page is not being passed to the `load.php` which is being refreshed by javascript every .....milliseconds so that online messages of the session id and the selected member should show in the message display.

Will be so grateful for your help programmers.

Comment: how do you pass `$_GET['id']` to `load.php`?

Answer (score 1):

add `$_GET['id']` value to your SESSION

```
$_SESSION['some_id'] = $_GET['id']
```

then use `$_SESSION['some_id']` in your query instead of `$_GET['id']`:

```
SELECT * FROM chat WHERE sender_id=$_SESSION['id'] AND receipent_id=$_SESSION['some_id']
```

Comment: Thanks. You mean add $_GET['id'] value to SESSION on the home page or add it in the load.php page?

Comment: @MKO on the page where $_GET['id'] is accessible. probably on the homepage, yes. Then this variable will be accessible through SESSION on any page (until user closes the browser)

Comment: I don't know if I am doing it right because it is not working for me. I am doing it this way;  session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
 $_SESSION['some_id'] = $_GET['id'];}. on the home page? is this right?